# Application start in global.asax

Tags: asp.net

I am developing my application in asp.net 3.5 and sql server 2005, and I want to record the visitor info into my database, like once the visitor enter my website, I'll insert his browser details to the database. [It's not necessary that visitor login my website].

Now I am confused where to put my code, If I put insert function in every page_load  then on every page it will execute and I'll not be able to get the exact number of visitor, visited my website.
Shall I go with application_start in Global.asax ??

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use session_start in the global.asax, that way it is only happening once per each user's visit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably put it in a [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zec9k340%28VS.71%29.aspx) and record the number of hits. Without logging users in, it would be difficult to know what constitutes a user "session" on your site, hence logging number of hits would be easier.

You might need to have a notice on your site to inform users of what information you are capturing.

Comment: Thanks Russ,
I am storing only browser info for my reference like Browser Name and Major Version.

I'll implement HttpModule.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage visitor on code level you need to start visitor counter under **Application_Start** method in application configuration file after need to increase the counter on every session.

```html
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code that runs when a new session is started
Application.Lock();
Application["NoOfVisitors"] = (int)Application["NoOfVisitors"] + 1;
Application.UnLock();
}
```

For more details follow the link given below.

http://www.freshcodehub.com/Article/49/show-number-of-visitors-in-aspnet-application